# I'm trying to initialize a 'score' object for a user, but the score object is null?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm in the process of creating a Java Spring Boot backend that gives Users (instances of the 'User' entity) a personality score, stored in a 'Score' entity object. This 'Score' object contains 5 int fields, one for each personality dimension (Like extraversion, intellect, emotional stability...etc) I try to initialize the 'Score' object for each User to contain '0' as the default value...upon creating an account, the user's 'Score' field should be non-null and populated with the value '0' for each personality dimension. I have a one-to-one mapping between each User and their 'Score' (Each user can have at max ONE personality score) There is an endpoint called 'submit-answers' where the currently logged in User sends their personality quiz answers to, where the User's 'score' object will be updated and recalculated.

I have two problems: when I register my User and create the User entity through my '/auth/register' endpoint, when I print out the value of the User's 'Score' object immediately after registration, I get a valid response; the Score object contains 5 dimensions/personality traits that are INTS, which are set to '0'. However, when I retrieve the User entity from my 'auth/myprofile' endpoint, all the other data about the User entity loads, but 'Score' is set to 'null'. Somewhere in my code, my 'Score' object is being initialized with '0' values but after registration and creation, something else is setting it to 'null'.

My second problem is when I try to contact the "/submit-answers" endpoint to send an array of key-value pairs (questions and answers) to my scoring mechanism, which will then update the current user's score, I get a "Duplicate entry '34' for key user_id" error in my spring boot backend, and a 500 internal server error from postman. For some reason, my backend attempts to add a 'Score' object to my Scores table with a 'null' user_id, which is causing the duplicate entry error (since there are multiple score objects in my database with null user_id). I'm trying to add a 'Score' object or update the current 'score' object for my user while associating it with the correct 'user_id' for the User. I don't see how user_id is becoming null in my code either.

Here I will post various parts of my code; my code for my 'User' entity, my code for my 'Score' entity, my controllers for my app, my Score calculation service, and my submit-answers quiz-scoring endpoint.

Note that in my error "Duplicate entry '34' for key user_id",  the line "scoreRepo.save(calculatedScore)" appears in my traceback.

QuizController.java (for my scoring endpoint)\

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Controller;


import com.wang.app.rest.Models.Answer;
import com.wang.app.rest.Models.AnswerInfo;
import com.wang.app.rest.Models.Score;
import com.wang.app.rest.Models.User;
import com.wang.app.rest.Repo.ScoreRepository;
import com.wang.app.rest.Repo.UserRepo;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.wang.app.rest.Service.ScoreCalculationService;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class QuizController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ScoreRepository scoreRepo;

    @Autowired
    private ScoreCalculationService scoreCalculationService; //inject the service into the controller

    private Map<Integer, AnswerInfo> questionToMap = new HashMap<>();
    //we use map interface type to make code more flexible...general map type
    //if we wanna change to a different type of map, we can do that easily
    //just change the right side of the assignment operator to a different type of map

    //(1) Extraversion, (2) Agreeableness, (3) Conscientiousness, (4) Emotional Stability, or (5) Intellect/Imagination)
    // and its direction of scoring (+ or -). These numbers should not be included in the actual survey questionnaire. For further information on scoring IPIP scales, click the following link:

    //keys in the hash map are the question numbers, values are the answer info objects
    @PostConstruct
    //this postConstruct ensures questionToMap is initialized as soon as controller is created, before requests made
    public void initQuestionToMap() {
        questionToMap.put(1, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(2, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(3, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(4, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(5, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(6, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(7, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(8, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(9, new AnswerInfo(4, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(10, new AnswerInfo(5, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(11, new AnswerInfo(1, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(12, new AnswerInfo(2, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(13, new AnswerInfo(3, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(14, new AnswerInfo(4, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(15, new AnswerInfo(5, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(16, new AnswerInfo(1, "-"));
        questionToMap.put(17, new AnswerInfo(2, "+"));
        questionToMap.put(18, new AnswerInfo(3, "-"));
   ....

    @Transactional
    @PostMapping("/submit-answers")
    public ResponseEntity<Score> submitAnswers(@RequestBody Map<Integer, Integer> answersData) {
        //Create a new user and save it to the database
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(currentUserName);


        if (user == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found");
        }


        //the input array must have keys and values
        //example of input array: {1:2, 2:4, 3:1}
        //left is question ID, right is answer value
        //this would be JSON, the keys and values are used to represent properties and values of an object 

        //Creating answer objects and associating them with the user
        List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        //looping over array of answers and creating answer objects
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : answersData.entrySet()) {
            Integer questionId = entry.getKey();
            Integer answerValue = entry.getValue();

            Answer answer = new Answer(questionId, answerValue);
            answer.setUser(user); // Associate the answer with the user
            answers.add(answer);  // Add the answer to the answers list
        }


        //Set answers for the user
        user.setAnswers(answers);

        //Calculating score based on answers
        Score calculatedScore = scoreCalculationService.calculateScore(answers, questionToMap);
        //added this

        Score existingScore = user.getScore();

        if (existingScore != null) {
            // Update the existing score with the new values
            existingScore.setExtraversion(calculatedScore.getExtraversion());
            existingScore.setAgreeableness(calculatedScore.getAgreeableness());
            existingScore.setConscientiousness(calculatedScore.getConscientiousness());
            existingScore.setEmotionalStability(calculatedScore.getEmotionalStability());
            existingScore.setIntellect(calculatedScore.getIntellect());

            scoreRepo.save(existingScore); // You'll need scoreRepo for this
        } else {
            // If user does not have an existing score, associate the new score with the user
            calculatedScore.setUser(user);
            user.setScore(calculatedScore);
            userRepo.save(user);
            scoreRepo.save(calculatedScore);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(calculatedScore);
            //do i need scoreRepo.save(calculatedScore??)
        }


        //Saving user to the database
        userRepo.save(user);

        //Return a response to the client
        return ResponseEntity.ok(existingScore);

    }
}
```

My 'User' entity:

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

//okay...now i need a way to handle image uploads....

@Entity
//lets us know user class will be table in database
public class User implements UserDetailsService {
    //this reads ,creates, update

    @Id
    //this tells mySQL that id will be uinque for each uer
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Answer> answers;
    //one to many: one user can have multiple answers
    //cascade setting ensures changes to user will be cascaded to answers

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Score score = new Score();
    //one to one: one user can have one score at most,,,
    //cascade setting ensures changes to user will be cascaded to score

    @Column
    //each attribute will be column in database
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column
    private String password;


    @Column
    private String university;

    @Column
    private String major;

    @Column
    private String gender;

    @Column
    private String attractedTo;

    @Column
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column
    private String instagram;

    @Column
    private String displayQuiz;

    @Column
    private Boolean displayQuizResults = false;

    @Lob //database stores this as a large object
    @Column(columnDefinition="MEDIUMBLOB")
    private byte[] profileImage;

    @Column
    private String about;

    //this id attribute is a primary key in database

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "matched_usernames", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "matched_username")
    private Set<String> matchedUsernames;  // Use Set to ensure uniqueness

    public Set<String> getMatchedUsernames() {
        return matchedUsernames;
    }

    public void setMatchedUsernames(Set<String> matchedUsernames) {
        this.matchedUsernames = matchedUsernames;
    }

    // A helper method
    public void addMatchedUsername(String username) {
        this.matchedUsernames.add(username);
    }

    // remove a username
    public void removeMatchedUsername(String username) {
        this.matchedUsernames.remove(username);
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }
    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        //this is a setter method
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Score getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Score score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUniversity(String university) {
        this.university = university;
    }

    public String getUniversity() {
        return this.university;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }

    public String getMajor(){
        return this.major;
    }

    public String getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAttractedTo(){
        return this.attractedTo;
    }

    public void setAttractedTo(String attractedTo){
        this.attractedTo = attractedTo;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getDisplayQuiz() {
        return this.displayQuiz;
    }

    public void setDisplayQuiz(String displayQuiz) {
        this.displayQuiz = displayQuiz;
        this.displayQuizResults = "Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(displayQuiz);
    }

    public void setDisplayQuizResults(Boolean displayQuizResults) {
        if(displayQuizResults == null) {
            this.displayQuizResults = false; // or true based on your requirement
        } else {
            this.displayQuizResults = displayQuizResults;
        }
    }

    public void setInstagram(String instagram) {
        this.instagram = instagram;
    }

    public String getInstagram() {
        return this.instagram;
    }


    public boolean getDisplayQuizResults() {
        return this.displayQuizResults;
    }


    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return null;
    }

    public byte[] getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(byte[] profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return this.about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }
}
```

My 'Score' entity:

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Entity

public class Score {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    //one to one means one score belongs to one user...each score assocaited with single user
    //joincolumn means foreign key column name user_id references primary key of user table

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int Extraversion;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int Agreeableness;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int Conscientiousness;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int EmotionalStability;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int Intellect;

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getExtraversion() {
        return Extraversion;
    }

    public void setExtraversion(int extraversion) {
        Extraversion = extraversion;
    }

    public int getAgreeableness() {
        return Agreeableness;
    }

    public void setAgreeableness(int agreeableness) {
        Agreeableness = agreeableness;
    }

    public int getConscientiousness() {
        return Conscientiousness;
    }

    public void setConscientiousness(int conscientiousness) {
        Conscientiousness = conscientiousness;
    }

    public int getEmotionalStability() {
        return EmotionalStability;
    }

    public void setEmotionalStability(int emotionalStability) {
        EmotionalStability = emotionalStability;
    }

    public int getIntellect() {
        return Intellect;
    }

    public void setIntellect(int intellect) {
        Intellect = intellect;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Score{" +
                "extraversion=" + getExtraversion() +
                ", agreeableness=" + getAgreeableness() +
                ", conscientiousness=" + getConscientiousness() +
                ", emotionalStability=" + getEmotionalStability() +
                ", intellect=" + getIntellect() +
                '}';
    }


}
```

My AuthController file (containing all other endpoints for my code)

```
package com.wang.app.rest.Controller;

import com.wang.app.rest.Dto.Create1Dto;
import com.wang.app.rest.Dto.Create2Dto;
import com.wang.app.rest.Dto.LoginDto;
import com.wang.app.rest.Dto.RegisterDto;
import com.wang.app.rest.Models.Score;
import com.wang.app.rest.Models.User;
import com.wang.app.rest.Repo.UserRepo;
import com.wang.app.rest.Service.MatchingService;
import com.wang.app.rest.Service.UserService;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MatchingService matchingService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody RegisterDto request) {
        // Check if a user with the same username already exists
        User existingUser = userRepo.findByUsername(request.getUsername());
        if (existingUser != null) {
            // Return an error response with a 400 (Bad Request) status code
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username already taken.");
        }


        // If no user with the same username exists, proceed with registration
        User registeredUser = userService.register(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());

        System.out.println("score is here"+ registeredUser.getScore());
        // Return a success response with a 200 (OK) status code
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }

    @PostMapping("/login") //this endpoint doesnt work...register works
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestBody LoginDto loginRequest) {
        boolean isAuthenticated = userService.authenticateUser(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword());

        if (isAuthenticated) {
            //typically would have jwt or session id
            // for my minimum viable product, we're returning a success message.
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Logged in successfully!");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid username or password.");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/update1")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserProfile(@RequestBody Create1Dto data) {
        //takes in a json....
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        System.out.println("this is my current user score from update1" + currentUser.getScore());

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }
        if (data.getFirstName()!= null){
            currentUser.setFirstName(data.getFirstName());
        }
        if (data.getLastName()!= null){
            currentUser.setLastName(data.getLastName());
        }
        if (data.getAge()!= 0) {
            currentUser.setAge(data.getAge());
        }

        if (data.getUniversity()!=null){
            currentUser.setUniversity(data.getUniversity());
        }

        if (data.getAbout()!=null){
            currentUser.setAbout(data.getAbout());
        }

        userRepo.save(currentUser);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Profile updated successfully");
    }

    @PostMapping("/update2")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserProfile2(@RequestBody Create2Dto data) {
        //takes in a json....
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println(authentication.getName());
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }

        currentUser.setMajor(data.getMajor());
        currentUser.setGender(data.getGender());
        currentUser.setAttractedTo(data.getAttractedTo());
        currentUser.setPhoneNumber(data.getPhoneNumber());
        currentUser.setDisplayQuiz(data.getDisplayQuiz());
        currentUser.setInstagram(data.getInstagram());


        userRepo.save(currentUser);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Profile updated successfully");
    }

    @PostMapping("/update3")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }

        try {
            byte[] imageBytes = file.getBytes();
            currentUser.setProfileImage(imageBytes);
            userRepo.save(currentUser);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Profile updated successfully");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error processing the image");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/iscreated")
    public ResponseEntity<?> isProfileImageCreated() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }

        // Check if the profileImage is not null
        if (currentUser.getProfileImage() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Profile image is complete");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Profile is not complete");
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Get the current authentication
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null) {
            // Clear the context
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

            // If sessions are used, invalidate the session
            request.getSession().invalidate();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Logged out successfully!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/myprofile")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCurrentUserProfile() {
        // get current user
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        // if auth is null, user is not authenticated
        if (authentication == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User is not authenticated");
        }

        // get username
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();

        // find user in database using name
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }

        // Return the user's data.....
        return ResponseEntity.ok(currentUser);
    }

    @PostMapping("/isloggedin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> isLoggedIn() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        // Check if authentication is not null, it's authenticated, and it's not an anonymous user
        if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated() &&
                !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {

            // Check if the username associated with the authentication is non-null
            String username = authentication.getName();
            if (username != null && !username.trim().isEmpty()) {
                // The user is authenticated and has a non-null username
                return ResponseEntity.ok("User is logged in");
            }
        }

        // The user is either not authenticated, or the associated username is null/empty
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User is not logged in");
    }

    @GetMapping("/similar-users")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSimilarUsers() {
        // Get the authentication of the current user
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("User is not authenticated");
        }

        // Get username from the authentication
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();

        // Fetch the user entity using the username
        User currentUser = userRepo.findByUsername(currentPrincipalName);

        if (currentUser == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("User not found");
        }

        // Fetch similar users using the MatchingService
        List<User> similarUsers = matchingService.findSimilarUsers(currentUser);

        // Convert the list of User objects to a list of usernames
        List<String> usernames = similarUsers.stream().map(User::getUsername).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(usernames);
    }


}
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to comment that there is a User entity table in my database that I created a LONG time ago, with the id of the user = 9, and when I call submit-answers with that user logged in, either through postman or via my front end, the submit-answers endpoint correctly and successfully updates my 'Score' object for that user, and user_id in the score table is '9', so that object is correctly associated with the id of the user...but when I register new users, the submit-answers endpoint doesn't work. I'm not sure if I should clear my database and start over to debug this.

Comment: I just dropped my schema entirely and created a new database. The error of 'duplicate entry '1' for key user_id" still persists when I contact the submit-answers endpoint after creating a user, even though the database is supposedly empty...

Comment: It seems that hibernate is inserting records twice each time in my spring boot log..I'm trying to find the source of the double-inserts

Comment: I FIXED IT! I realized that since I set CASCADE.TYPE=ALL between the User and Score entities, I didn't need to save both the User and the Score in their repos inside submit-answers....I changed it to save only the User inside userrepo and removed the scorerepo saves...now hibernate only updates once!